# What are the best avenues for employment for a new Doctor of Management Information Systems Technology?

Tags: career-path, early-career

I will have my degree soon. I am waiting for QRF approval and preparing for my Oral Defense. Suddenly I feel a bit unsure about how I will make this degree pay for itself. I am not sure that my Doctorate will get me an advancement with my current employer and I want to have a path for applying what I have learned. I do like the research aspect of the title but I want to do more.

What are the best avenues for employment for a new Doctor of Management Information Systems Technology, for example, teaching or doing research for a university?

Comment: Since this is tagged [tag:postdocs], are you specifically looking for a postdoc in your field?  Or are you more broadly asking for career pathways?

Comment: I am asking for career pathways.

Comment: At SE.Academia, job-hunting isn't typically considered on-topic unless you're specifically asking about hunting for academic jobs, e.g. as a post-doc, instructor, researcher, or professor.  If you edit this question to that more restricted set of career pathways, it might be on-topic (dunno about the "_shopping question_" constraint).  But if you're more interested in private-sector jobs, this might be on-topic at [SE.Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, now I get how this works. I will edit the question as I am interested in the academic side as well. For example, I would not mind teaching.